# Accessing Object Properties returned from ASP.net

Tags: php, asp.net, parsing, properties

I'm working on my first from-scratch back end project. Forgive my ignorance.

I have a page that's filled by data returned from an ASP.net API. I'm connecting to the API successfully using `SoapClient`, but I'm unable to successfully parse the results.

**How can I echo Status in the object below?**

The returned object is:

```
stdClass Object(
    [LoginResult] => {
        "Result":{
            "Status":"FAILED",
            "Message":"Access Denied"},
        "SessionToken":""
    }
)
```

My code is:

`$loginResult->Result;`

The error I receive is:

`Undefined property: stdClass::$Result`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$loginResult` is the variable of the returned result then it is an object with a property `LoginResult` that contains a JSON encoded object.  Once decoded as an array, it has a `Result` key array containing the keys `Status` and `Message`:

```
$array = json_decode($loginResult->LoginResult, true);
echo $array['Result']['Status'];
```

If you don't pass `true` to `json_decode` then you get a decoded object containing another object and would use:

```
$object = json_decode($loginResult->LoginResult);
echo $object->Result->Status;
```

In PHP >= 5.4.0 you should be able to do:

```
echo json_decode($loginResult->LoginResult, true)['Result']['Status'];
// or
echo json_decode($loginResult->LoginResult)->Result->Status;
```

Comment: This makes sense, thank you for the explanation. Do you have a preference between the first two formats (for performance or cleanliness)? I'm leaning towards the latter.

Comment: It shouldn't matter either way.  I didn't notice that the JSON was an object at first that's why the answer starts with an array.  Might as well just stick with an object.